# Elastic Search not giving exact results python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using match phrase query to find in ES. but i have noticed that the results returned are not appropriate.
code --

```
      res = es.search(index=('indice_1'),

               body = {
    "_source":["content"],

    "query": {
        "match_phrase":{
        "content":"xyz abc"
        }}}

   ,
size=500,
scroll='60s')
```

It doesn't get me records where content is -
"hi my name isxyz abc." and "hey wassupxyz abc. how is life"

doing a similar search in mongodb using using regex gets both the records as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What analyzers are you using?

Comment: I am new to ES . I am not using any.

Comment: Should I use any specific analyser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't specify an analyzer then you are using [`standard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) by default. It will do grammar based tokenization. So your terms for the phrase "hi my name isxyz abc." will be something like `[hi, my, name, isxyz, abc]` and `match_phrase` is looking for the terms `[xyz, abc]` right next to each other (unless you specify `slop`).

You can either use a different analyzer or modify your query. If you use a `match` query, it will match on the term "abc". If you want the phrase to match, you'll need to use a different analyzer. [NGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) should work for you.

Here's an example:

```
PUT test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test_index/_doc/1
{
  "content": "hi my name isxyz abc."
}

PUT test_index/_doc/2
{
  "content": "hey wassupxyz abc. how is life"
}

POST test_index/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "content": "xyz abc"
    }
  }
}
```

That results in finding both documents.

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.5753642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "content": "hey wassupxyz abc. how is life"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "content": "hi my name isxyz abc."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
If you're looking to do a `wildcard` query, you can use the `standard` analyzer. The use case you specified in the comments would be added like this:

```
PUT test_index/_doc/3
{
  "content": "RegionLasit Pant0Q00B000001KBQ1SAO00"
}
```

And you can query it with `wildcard`:

```
POST test_index/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "content.keyword": {
        "value": "*Lasit Pant*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially you are doing a substring search without the `nGram` analyzer. Your query phrase will then just be `"*<my search terms>*"`. I would still recommend looking into `nGrams`.

Comment: i just read the ngram tokenizer. for the current use case the min length 3 would suffice. is there any specific/ generic way ? 
like in mongodb i used regex.

Comment: You can either use the `query_string` or a `wildcard` search. If you do use `wildcard` you might want to run it against the keyword. e.g. `POST test_index/_doc/_search {"query": {"wildcard": {"content.keyword": {"value": "*xyz abc*"}}}}` Note that using the `"content.keyword"` field will make the query case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this. it worked only on certain case. 
but "RegionLasit Pant0Q00B000001KBQ1SAO00" in this case i used Lasit Pant as search word. it didn't get my this document.

Comment: @LasitPant did you use the `*` for wildcards? Essentially was your query for `"*Lasit Pant*"` or just for `"Lasit Pant"`?

Comment: @LasitPant For the `wildcard` query you would need to use the `*` to cover that use case. Alternatively, you can still use `nGrams` for this.

Comment: * Lasit Pant * @tim i used inside  * xya * . no success.

Comment: thanks. i am upvoting  the answer. but after reading the ngram approach.
the wildcard takes more computation time. Still thanks a lot for showing me the path fro ngram approach.

Comment: @tim- off topic. can i add ngram tokeniser to an existing indice ?

Comment: @LasitPant - To add `nGram` you will need to create a new index and then you can use `_reindex` to copy the documents from your existing index.

Comment: Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can also use type parameter to set to  phrase in the query

```
 res = es.search(index=('indice_1'),

               body = {
    "_source":["content"],

    "query": {
        "query":"xyz abc"
        },
        type:"phrase"}

   ,
size=500,
scroll='60s')
```

Comment: @pratik- 
<class 'type'>: 'phrase'}, TypeError('keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not type',))
i get this i am using ES  6.4